# int.Parse(ToString) Different than (int)

Tags: c#, parsing, casting

I have an `object` that holds a number greater than zero(granted). Let's give it 42. It's originally part of a `HttpContext.Session` collection.

```
Session["myNumber"] = 42;
object obj = Session["myNumber"];
```

I've tried using it as an int with casting:

```
int num = (int)obj;
```

This returns `0`.

However, I managed to get what I want doing:

```
int num = int.Parse(obj.ToString());
```

This gives me `42`.

Does this make sense, might it be a problem with declarations or types or something?

Comment: please show how you declare `obj` and how you assign its value, that will be the key

Comment: How are you assigning 42 to `obj`?

Comment: I'd really be interested in the output of obj.GetType(). =)

Comment: @Jens - System.String. I was thrown off by the fact it demanded a `ToString()` in the `Parse` function. Good job :)

Comment: In this case, `(int)obj` should really throw an InvalidCastException. Do you by any chance catch `Exception` anywhere?

Comment: I tried the code you posted and get 42 and 42 both times, and `int` for the type of `obj`. You appear to be doing something other than what you show here.

Comment: @JNF the fact that you put in `42` and get back a `String` makes me very suspicious that there is something very different going on in your application that isn't visible in the snippets you've shown. Is `Session` your own thing? or the framework's? Are the two operations on `obj` (`0` vs `42`) done *at the same time*? any chance something like threading is the actual problem here? The problem is: you haven't posted enough for us to reproduce this in isolation. That makes us conclude: the bug is in the code you aren't showing us.

Comment: @Jens, actually, there was an exception. A `catch` block which didn't throw an exception was missed by me while debugging.

Comment: @JNF so is that the mystery solved? a dodgy `catch` block?

Comment: Yes. VS didn't think `(int)Session["var"]` is a problem before runtime but it actually threw an exception, I guess because it was read as `String`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you describe simply doesn't happen.

If you get the value `0` when unboxing an object, then the object actally contains a boxed `int`, and it actually has the value `0`.

The only way to unbox a value is to use the exact type of the value, which means that you would get an exception if it was anything other than an `int`.

There has to be something else in your code that causes this.

Comment: "What you describe simply doesn't happen." ... except for the bit where I actually do it ;p

Comment: @Jens custom conversion operators are not used when the variable's type is `object` - it is a straight unboox

Comment: @MarcGravell: Nice hack. It would be possible to create an object that actually does that, but certainly not using `Session["myNumber"] = 42;`.

Comment: to be fair, that line wasn't there when I started being evil

Comment: While @MarcGravell's answer was fun, I suupose your's is most accurate.

Answer (score 5):

The key point I'm trying to make below is that yes it might be possible ***if*** the actual `obj` is not really an `int` but is something sufficiently `int`-like for the unbox to work. In terms of making sense of it, the main thing I would look at here is: what is `obj.GetType()`.

OK, evil code: - first the important bit:

```
static void Main()
{
    object obj = Evil();
    int i = (int)obj; // 0
    int j = int.Parse(obj.ToString()); // 42
}
```

How did I do this monstrosity?

I lied and cheated... basically, I did this:

```
enum bar {
    @42 = 0 // not legal C#... "42" is not a valid identifier
}
```

But at the CLI level it is valid...

```
static object Evil()
{
    var ab = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(
        new AssemblyName("foo"), AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
    var mb = ab.DefineDynamicModule("foo");
    var eb = mb.DefineEnum("bar", TypeAttributes.Public, typeof(int));
    eb.DefineLiteral("42", 0);
    Type t = eb.CreateType();
    return Enum.ToObject(t, 0);
}
```

Comment: Or you could just define a class with an explicit int conversion that returns 0, and a ToString that returns "42"?

Comment: @Rawling no, implicit / explicit conversions are not used if the variable type is `object`

Comment: BTW, `GetType()` gives `System.String`.

Comment: Wait a sec, `Session["MyNumber"]` could be a reference type that defines an explicit conversion to int.  Then, when you assign that to `object`, the actual type of the object won't change (converting a reference type of `object` is a no-op).

Comment: @MartinBaulig custom conversions are not used if the variable type is `object`.

Comment: @JNF are you sure you don't have a `try`/`catch` somewhere? a string reference simply doesn't unbox to an int... what is the string contents?

Comment: @JNF also, if you do `Session["myNumber"] = 42;`, then that is not a `string`... `GetType()` should not report `String`. I think there's something in your code you're not showing us.

Comment: There was a `catch`. It wasn't throwing an error so I missed it.

Comment: Ok, so the real question here is what's the return type of that `Session` indexer?  If it's a reference type, then you could assign it to a variable of type `object` and custom conversions will be executed.

But if it's really string, then this all shouldn't make any sense.  Confused ....

Comment: @MartinBaulig see the recent comments on the question; it was just a dodgy `catch`

Comment: Oh, ok, mystery solved :-)  I also just checked the MSDN docs and the return value of `HttpContext.Session ["myNumber"]` is actually `object`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does make sense as '42' can be represented in many ways. Is it a string? Is it an integer? Is it a hex string? Is it bananas and oranges (not joking)?

So when you asked C# "int.Parse" you told C# "this thingy is an integer using standard C# string notation for an integer.

When you told C# with the line "(int)obj" you were saying this thingy is already an integer just as you like it.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

When I execute the code

```
        object obj = 42;

        int num = (int)obj; 

        int num2 = int.Parse(obj.ToString());
```

It returns 42 in both cases.

So, your obj must be something other than object (as you stated).  So we would rneed the declared type og obj to answer this further.